# NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0 returning 992 instead of 993?

Tags: xcode, ios6

I'm trying to detect the ios version of a device:

```
  if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
        {
            NSLog(@"iOS Type: iOS7");
            self.iosType = IOS_7;
        } else if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0){
            NSLog(@"iOS Type: iOS6");
            self.iosType = IOS_6;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"iOS Type: iOS5 or below");
            self.iosType = IOS_5_BELOW;
        }
```

However when I run it on my ios 6 simulator, it returns 992 as opposed to 993 like it's defined in NSObjCRuntime.

```
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0  993.00
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1  993.00
```

Is this just a simulator issue that works on real ios6 devices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue, and done a lot of research in order to resolve it.
The issue was resolved by updating the Xcode : the version of my Xcode was 4.6.3, and there is no automatic update to get the Xcode 5.1, so you have to do it manually and you are not notified of the presence of this update. 
In conclusion, the issue is not related with the simulator, it is related with the version of Xcode. You just have to get the newest version.

My 2 cents